# reformat HTTP request from json file to raw

Tags: awk

i have multiple files which is HTTP request in json file format and every file content as following .

```
{
    "http://testphp.vulnweb.com/search.php": {
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Connection": "close",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "params": [
            "goButton",
            "searchFor"
        ]
    }
}%
```

desired output is raw request as following

```
POST /search.php HTTP/1.1
Host: testphp.vulnweb.com
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.30
Connection: close

searchFor=a&goButton=go
```

and BTW the default char in the end of lines is `\r\n` as it the default format of HTTP raw request and there is extra `\r\n` in the line before parameters.
i really don`t know if awk could handle this or not but if it how hard it will be??
plz also recommend any online solution to do so if i have to go that way because i struggling in search for reformat from json to raw request.

Thanks

Comment: `awk` seems to be ill-suited here (processing JSON). Are you strictly limited to `awk` or are you allowed to use other tools? If second please consider using one which provides support for working with JSON.

Comment: @Daweo it is not limited to awk it just first tool come to my mind for processing test, if you know other. suggestion is most welcomed !

Comment: Where is `23` (Content-Length) in your JSON file?

Comment: @Cyrus the tool which has this json output dose not gives content length

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired exact output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: The usual rule of thumb when parsing serialized data or markup is to use a parser specifically designed to deal with that data. In this case, on the linux command line, `jq` is probably best suited. It will be a bit of work to get this output, but `jq` and maybe some `cut` or similar to deal with the strings that `jq` spits out is totally doable.

Comment: Your JSON has in params `goButton` and `searchFor` whilst desired output `searchFor=a&goButton=go`. There is not information regarding `a` and `go` (values for params) in JSON. This task is impossible to do (more information in output than in input).